# SQL GROUP BY with CASE and CAST DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I have below source table in SQL which I would like to query to get output table as per below to have sum of amount from each source aggregated by date without time. Unfortunately my code doesn't work.

| ID | Amount | Source | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | Source1 | 2023-09-07 16:00:00 |
| 2 | 20 | Source2 | 2023-09-07 19:00:00 |
| 3 | 30 | Source1 | 2023-09-08 12:00:00 |
| 4 | 15 | Source1 | 2023-09-09 11:00:00 |
| 5 | 12 | Source2 | 2023-09-08 17:00:00 |
| 6 | 11 | Source1 | 2023-09-07 14:00:00 |
| 7 | 18 | Source2 | 2023-09-07 13:00:00 |

Expected output:

| Amount_Source1 | Amount_Source2 | NewDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 38 | 2023-09-07 |
| 30 | 12 | 2023-09-08 |
| 15 | 0 | 2023-09-09 |

My code:

```
SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE) as NewDate,
CASE WHEN Source = 'Source1'
 THEN Amount
END AS Amount_Source1
CASE WHEN Source = 'Source2'
 THEN Amount
END AS Amount_Source2
GROUP BY CAST(Date AS DATE), Amount, Source
```

Comment: add SUM around the case whens and remove amount and source from group by

Comment: Probably you should learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  What's the point of grouping with aggregating anything?

Comment: Your logic should be you are grouping by date, you sum the amount within the date grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Your example code seems to be missing `FROM`.

You were most of the way there, you just needed to aggregate on the columns you didn't want to group by:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, Amount INT, Source NVARCHAR(10), Date DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, Amount, Source, Date) VALUES
(1, 10, 'Source1', '2023-09-07 16:00:00'),
(2, 20, 'Source2', '2023-09-07 19:00:00'),
(3, 30, 'Source1', '2023-09-08 12:00:00'),
(4, 15, 'Source1', '2023-09-09 11:00:00'),
(5, 12, 'Source2', '2023-09-08 17:00:00'),
(6, 11, 'Source1', '2023-09-07 14:00:00'),
(7, 18, 'Source2', '2023-09-07 13:00:00');

SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE) as NewDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Source1' THEN Amount END) AS Amount_Source1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Source2' THEN Amount END) AS Amount_Source2
  FROM @Table
GROUP BY CAST(Date AS DATE);
```

| NewDate | Amount_Source1 | Amount_Source2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-07 | 21 | 38 |
| 2023-09-08 | 30 | 12 |
| 2023-09-09 | 15 |  |

You may want to consider changing the datatype of `Amount` to a decimal value if it's going to record currency values. `DECIMAL` is a good choice for this. It has two properties: `SCALE` and `PRECISION` which you'd also need to specify. `PRECISION` is the total number of digits, while `SCALE` is the number after the decimal point. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: great answer, you might wanna wrap the SUM in ISNULL(, 0)

Comment: Probably not an ISNULL but more `ELSE 0 END` on the CASE but still a good answer with good explanation.  OP does have less than optimal names and perhaps column types - good note there.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you are missing a `SUM` function. The following code should do as you expect:

```
SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE) as NewDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Source1'
         THEN Amount
         END) AS Amount_Source1
    SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Source2'
         THEN Amount
         END) AS Amount_Source2
GROUP BY CAST(Date AS DATE)
```

When using a `GROUP BY` it's important to understand that it is intended to instruct SQL how you want your data aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to answer by another but slightly different syntax than a `CASE` statement set.

```
DECLARE @SourceTable TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Amount INT,
    [Source] VARCHAR(7),
    [Date] DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO @SourceTable (
    ID,
    Amount,
    [Source],
    [Date]
    )
VALUES
    (1, 10, 'Source1', '2023-09-07 16:00:00'),
    (2, 20, 'Source2', '2023-09-07 19:00:00'),
    (3, 30, 'Source1', '2023-09-08 12:00:00'),
    (4, 15, 'Source1', '2023-09-09 11:00:00'),
    (5, 12, 'Source2', '2023-09-08 17:00:00'),
    (6, 11, 'Source1', '2023-09-07 14:00:00'),
    (7, 18, 'Source2', '2023-09-07 13:00:00');
SELECT
    SUM(IIF(t.[Source] = 'Source1', t.Amount, 0)) AS Amount_Source1,
    SUM(IIF(t.[Source] = 'Source2', t.Amount, 0)) AS Amount_Source2,
    CAST(t.[Date] AS DATE) AS NewDate
FROM @SourceTable AS t
GROUP BY CAST(t.[Date] AS DATE);
```

| Amount_Source1 | Amount_Source2 | NewDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 38 | 2023-09-07 |
| 30 | 12 | 2023-09-08 |
| 15 | 0 | 2023-09-09 |